# Cannot initialize pointer to a subclass with base clase rvalue

Tags: c++, pointers, polymorphism

I have a question regarding a problem in a C++ exam. I had quite an argument with a teaching assistant and I want to know, if I missed something.

Given is the following code:

```
class Student {
public:
  virtual void checkFinanes() {
    std::cout << "I have no money. \n";
  }
};

class ExonomyStudent : public Student {
public:
  virtual void checkFinances() {
    std::cout << "I am making a lot of money.\n";
  }
};
```

The question is:

> Does the following code compile? If so, what is the output on the console when i is expected. If not, why not?

```
Student student;
student.checkFinances();
EconomyStudent* economyStudent = &student;
economyStudent->checkFinances();
```

And the answer is supposed to be:

> Does not compile. Cannot initialize EconomyStudent * with Student rvalue.

I am aware and understand, that one cannot initialize a pointer to a subclass with and address of an object of a baseclase and that this does not compile. What I don't understand is the rvalue. Is it really important that rvalue is stated to make the answer valid? My teaching assistant insisted but I don't think so. What do you think?

Comment: ...but `student` is an lvalue here? In any case, you are right that this is not a matter of value categories at all.

Comment: While `&student` is an rvalue, its rvalue-ness is not the cause of the error, and it's not a "Student rvalue".

Comment: Maybe they meant to have `Cannot initialize EconomyStudent * with Student* rvalue` since `&student` gives you an rvalue.  As is though the message is wrong.

Comment: It doesn't compile because of numerous mispellings. I suggest you fix the code and run it through online compiler, and check for yourself what is an error message.

Comment: On a side note, I would be super surprised if your TA actually understand value categories in modern C++. Very few people do.

Answer (score 5):

> Is it really important that rvalue is stated to make the answer valid?

I don't think so. Check the case where you try to initialize `EconomyStudent *economyStudent` with an lvalue:

```
 Student student;
 student.checkFinances();
 Student *lvalue = &student;
 EconomyStudent* economyStudent = lvalue;
```

`clang` complains on my machine, stating that

> error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'EconomyStudent *' with an lvalue of type 'Student *'

Hence, the only difference in terms of compiler output is rvalue vs. lvalue. As the value category has nothing to do with the type of error in the snippet, you can tell your teaching assistant that some random user on the internet thinks that you are right.

Comment: From a standard perspective, this is a `prvalue`, right? [\[conv.ptr\]](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.ptr) says _"A prvalue of type “pointer to cv D”, where D is a class type, can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to cv B”, where B is a base class ([class.derived]) of D."_ (and a `prvalue` _"is an expression whose evaluation initializes an object [...]"_). Not that I would expect the compiler to express itself in legalese, but maybe this is where the TA's opinion stems from (not that I support it)?

Comment: Yes, maybe?! But that almost sounds like a TA reading the standard first and then creating such a question to exactly tackle the wording of a particular section. I wish my TAs would have been motivated enough to do such things^^

Comment: I agree that it's a pretty far-fetched explanation, I just stumbled on the `prvalue` stuff while trying to build a standard-backed answer that could be used to convince the TA.